Transcendality basis: Decomposing Bessel function value into infinite series of essentially only Eulers' number?
While trying to understand Euler's number and Bessel functions better I thought:

Is it possible to decompose Bessel functions in terms of an infinite series involving Euler's number $e$?

Take $K_1(2)$ for example. I've always wondered if this constant can be expressed in terms of an infinite series of constants that are Euler's number.
With a bit of geometric thinking we can get the following result:
$$ \int_0^{1/e} e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}~dx=\frac{1}{2e^2}+K_1(2).$$
We can iterate over the $K_1(2)$ term expressing it in terms of $e$ and essentially obtaining a nested sum, which is apparently an avenue to potentially concluding that $K_1(2)$ is a transcendental number. (This is currently an open problem in the field of transcendental number theory).
Let's take a look at a longer iteration:
$$ \int_0^{1/e} e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}~dx=\frac{1}{2e^2}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2e^2}+\bigg(\frac{1}{2}I_1+I_2\bigg)\bigg)$$
where I've used $$I_2:=\int_{1/e}^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}~dx$$
And $$ I_1:=\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}~dx=2K_1(2) $$
Thus we can continue this indefinitely leaving $K_1(2)$ exactly equal to a series involving Eulers number and potentially concluding the transcendentality of $K_1(2)$.

I tend to understand $I_1$ to be a transcendental number as it boils down to a nesting of $1/2$ and $e^2.$ Am I correct to say this?


The implications are that $K_1(2)$ is also transcendental then. Is this true though? Because there really should be a rigorous way to say that as the iterations go to infinity, only $1/2$ and $e^2$ are the terms in the infinite nested sum. I think there is a way to pose that concept rigorously but I need some help with it.

Thanks for any insights on this!
